# Determine a normal vector to the tangent plane of a graph of a multivariate function $P(x,y)$ at $(x,y)$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let there be a multivariate function $P(x,y)$. I want to determine the normal vector to the tangent plane at that point $(x,y)$. The reason for this is that I want to be able to place a 3D model on top of the graph of a multivariate function and so I want to be able to rotate it to the proper orientation. The normal vector is sufficient for what I need.

I have a means of taking the derivative of multivariate functions I define using objects in programming so I don't need any way of approximating or anything like that. I just don't know what equation gives the normal vector to the graph of a multivariate function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation for the tangent plane at point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ on the surface $z=P(x,y)$ is given by $$z=P(x_0,y_0)+\partial_x P(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)+\partial_y P(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)$$
which we may identify as being a plane through $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ with (unnormalized) normal vector $$\mathbf{n}=(-\partial_x P(x_0,y_0),-\partial_y P(x_0,y_0),1).$$
Equivalently, $\mathbf{n}=\nabla(z-P(x,y))$.